# Where did the question concerning YHWH/Elohim being part of the Egyptian/Canaanite pantheon go?

Tags: discussion, moderation, scope

I'm sure that one of these questions was decent among all the guff that was appearing on here yesterday? Did it get deleted? Was it off-topic and if so why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I deleted them. Each had been closed already, and each were far enough off-topic that there was little hope if editing them into shape. That's evidenced by the closure by the community and,the amount of down-votes.

Cleaning up low quality content by deleting it is standard operating procedure on all StackExchange sites.

In each case, I left a comment for the OP and they are more fully aware of the reason for deletion. I see no need to go further in explaining the action with the community at large. The OP has a more full explanation already. If the OP disagrees or has an issue with it, they can take it up with the moderators by flagging or posting here themselves.

Because the goal of moderation is to keep the site healthy ***and*** to help new members fit in, I've also provided links to the help page and various Meta post to help explain what's on topic and how to participate constructively if they choose to do so in the future.

If the OP has any interest in participating constructively, they're more than welcome to edit the questions to be re-opened, or to post new ones that are on-topic and serious.

Comment: Fair enough. I was preparing an answer - never mind.

Comment: There was one left from your cleanup that I deleted after you left. It was the best of the bunch but it still had all the properties you cite and I deleted it for much the same reasons. It wasn't going to go anywhere.

Comment: I think the OP is back, and is creating lots of accounts. Can you check IPs?